# Find generating function of $\frac{5-3x}{2-3x+x^2}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Find generating function of $\frac{5-3x}{2-3x+x^2}$.

My attempt: $\frac{5-3x}{2-3x+x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (5-3x) \cdot \frac{1}{1-x/2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x}$. Here you use geometric series, but I don't know, how to find the coefficient before $x^n$ in this form.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using the zig cosine rule

Comment: This **is** the generating function, nothing to find there. What you are trying to find is the coefficient sequence of its power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5-3x}{2-3x+x^2}=&\frac{5-3x}{\left( x-1 \right) \left( x-2 \right)}
\\
=&\frac{2}{1-x}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{x}{2}}
\\
=&2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x^n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left( \frac{x}{2} \right) ^n}
\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left( 2+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) x^n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh, i see, partial fractions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another method with your method:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5-3x}{2-3x+x^2}=&\frac{1}{2}\left( 5-3x \right) \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}
\\
=&\left( 5-3x \right) \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x^n}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left( \frac{x}{2} \right) ^n}
\\
=&\frac{5-3x}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}{x^m\left( \frac{x}{2} \right) ^n}}
\\
=&\frac{5-3x}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{m+n}}{2^n}}}
\\
=&\frac{5-3x}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{m+n=k}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^k}{2^n}}}
\\
=&\frac{5-3x}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^k{\frac{1}{2^n}x^k}}
\\
=&\frac{5-3x}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^{k+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}x^k}
\\
=&\left( 5-3x \right) \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\left( 1-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^{k+1} \right) x^k}
\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\left( 5\left( 1-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^{k+1} \right) -3\left( 1-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^k \right) \right) x^k}
\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\left( 2+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \right) x^k}
\end{align}
$$